# Ajax/jquery function not receiving id from returned JSON/PHP table cell value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I've created a table (for use with datatables) from a JSON array and I have embedded a link in the array which has an ID (the primary key from the mysql table) which then is supposed to trigger a dynamic modal that pulls up additional information. The particular line embedded in the JSON looks like this:

in PHP:

```
$results['provider_name'] = "<a id='".$results['id']."' data-toggle='modal' href='#provmodal' class='push'>".$results['provider_name']."</a>";
```

but in JSON the provider name field looks like this:

```
"provider_name":"COTTAGE GROVE COMMUNITY HOSPITAL<\/a>"
```

A side effect of this is that it makes the remaining JSON a link when I echo it on the page. This doesn't seem to affect the display on the page though.

When the table cell is generated it contains the `id="#"` as well as the modal trigger information and the `class="push"` which successfully triggers my modal, but there is no information inside of it which led me to believe that it wasn't receiving the ID from the line and triggering the `success:` function.

Here's what the fully generated table cell looks like:

`<a id="96" data-toggle="modal" href="#provmodal" class="push">COTTAGE GROVE COMMUNITY HOSPITAL</a>`

Here is my ajax script for the modal -->

```
$(function(){
    $('.push').on('click', function(){
      var ele_id = $(this).attr('id');
      console.log(ele_id);
       $.ajax({
          type : 'post',
           url : 'modalquery_providerlist.php', // in here you should put your query 
          data :  'post_id='+ ele_id, // here you pass your id via ajax .
                     // in php you should use $_POST['post_id'] to get this value 
       success : function(r)
           {
              // now you can show output in your modal 
        $("#provmodal .modal-body").html(r).promise().done(function(){
        $("#provmodal").modal('show');  
                     });
           }
         });
    });
 });
```

`console.log()` is returning nothing when I click the modal trigger so I know it's not receiving it from `id` attribute.

Am I properly embedding my link in the json?

I'm a little baffled as I actually have this script working on another page, the only difference is it's not an external ajax json source. I'm generating the json array right on the page and echoing it into a javascript variable for datatables 'aaData' and filling the table that way. I'd prefer to request the json externally though and that's where I ran into this issue.

:Edit:

here is modalquery_providerlist.php as requested -->

```
<?php
include_once("functions.php");
require_once("link_provlist_2013.php");
$id = $_POST['post_id'];

$modalquery = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM prov_stats WHERE id = :id");
$modalquery->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$modalquery->execute();
$modalresults = $modalquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

//calc fields
$adc = ($modalresults['pat_days']/365);
$alos = ($modalresults['pat_days']/$modalresults['disc']);
if($modalresults['total_charity_uncomp_cost'] != 0){
$charity_disp = "\$".number_format($modalresults['total_charity_uncomp_cost']);
} else {
    $charity_disp = "<b style='color:red'>Not Reported</b>";
}
$all_other = 100 - ((($modalresults['medicare']/$modalresults['disc']) * 100) + (($modalresults['medicaid']/$modalresults['disc']) * 100));

//printing onto the modal
print_r("<img width='225' height='100' class='pull-right' src='/photoshop/hds/logo_mini_fade.png' />");
print_r("<h4>Name: ".$modalresults['provider_name']."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>Licensed Beds: ".$modalresults['lic_beds']."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>Net Patient Revenue: "."\$".number_format($modalresults['net_patient_rev'])."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>Net Income: "."\$".number_format($modalresults['net_income'])."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>Discharges: ".number_format($modalresults['disc'])."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>Patient Days: ".number_format($modalresults['pat_days'])."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>ADC: ".sprintf("%.1f",$adc)."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>ALOS: ".sprintf("%.1f",$alos)." Days</h4>");
print_r("<h4>Total Charity and Uncompensated Care Costs: ".$charity_disp."</h4>");
print_r("<hr/ style='width: 100%; color: black; height: 1px; background-color:black;'>");
print_r("<h4><b>Payer Mix (Discharges):</b></h4>");
print_r("<h4>Medicare: ".sprintf("%.1f%%", ($modalresults['medicare']/$modalresults['disc']) * 100)." </h4>");
print_r("<h4>Medicaid: ".sprintf("%.1f%%", ($modalresults['medicaid']/$modalresults['disc']) * 100)." </h4>");
print_r("<h4>All Other: ".sprintf("%.1f%%", $all_other)." </h4>");
print_r("<hr/ style='width: 100%; color: black; height: 1px; background-color:black;'>");
/*print_r("<h4>Urban/Rural Code: ".$modalresults['urban_or_rural']."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>Ownership Type: ".$modalresults['ownership_type']."</h4>");*/
print_r("<h4>State: ".$modalresults['state']."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>City: ".$modalresults['city']."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>Street: ".$modalresults['street']."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>Zip: ".$modalresults['zip']."</h4>");
print_r("<h4>County: ".$modalresults['county']."</h4>");
?>
```

Comment: Can you show your PHP code?

Comment: Just a side note I have tried echo instead of print_r, but it produced no difference

Comment: Why so much print_r? try collecting everything in one variable and then echo the variable at the end with exit. eg echo $html;exit;

Comment: @AnandGhaywankar it's old code, I will go ahead and change it but it doesn't solve my problem the modal is still empty